# How servlets container instantiates external classes used by servlets?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets

I know one Servlets instance is shared by multiple threads for handling concurrent requests. Inside the servlets, I will call other **thread-safe classes**: `ExternalClassOne` which in turn calls `ExternalClassTwo`.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ExternalClassOne cOne = new ExternalClassOne();
    cOne.doSomething();     
   //doSomething() will also use other classes like ExternalClassTwo, ExternalClassThree...
  }
}
```

I have some questions:

1. How many instances of the classes `ExternalClassOne`, `ExternalClassTwo` will be created?
2. If they are created per thread for each request (e.g., 100 concurrent requests = 100 instances of `ExternalClassOne`), does making them singleton increase the performance? Does Tomcat have any "magic" to reuse thread-safe instance where possible?

Comment: Each time `new ExternalClassOne()` is executed, a new instance is created. That's the purpose of `new`. Tomcat has nothing to do with that, and can't control anything: new creates an instance, whatever your environment is.

Answer (score 1):

Instances are created on each execution of `new`, as already stated in the comment above.
Careful with singletons: To obtain the instance needs a synchronized method invocation, and this ruins the responsiveness of your application. 
Tomcat does not provide any such means afaik, but the Java library. You may use ThreadLocals. 
Otherwise, create the (thread-safe) classes in a `ContextListener` on application startup and put them in the app context, so each servlet can get them from there.